# Timeout error when programmatically rendering SSRS report through ReportExecution2005.asmx

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, web-services

I have a task that calls the SSRS report server to render the report, then places the freshly rendered report into a SharePoint document library.  The report server is set up in SharePoint Integrated Mode.

For smaller reports, everything works perfectly.  However, if a report take longer than about 90 seconds to generate, the call to render throws an exception of "The operation has timed out".

My proxy's timeout value is set to -1.
(RSExecClient.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)

The httpRuntime's exeuction timeout is set to "9000" for both the SharePoint web site's, well as the report server's, web.config files.

Also, I have set the DatabaseQueryTimeout to "0" in the rsreportserver.config file.

I am connecting to the ssrs web service using "https:///_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx".

I also noticed that I could connect through "http://:8080/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx", however it seems I have to handle authentication and authorization myself, which caused other troubles.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or at least of a logging location that I can go to for more information?

Thanks, 
Michael

Answer (score 1):

try checking the timeout property on the database connection itself (DataSource).

Keep in mind there are .config fies where the httpruntime is defined one for the Report 
Server and another for the Report Manager. I got bitten with this a few days ago.

SSRS logs files and locations are documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are some senarios that you face reprting service timing out because of the memory issue.
The issue is reporting services release memory and it will take time to allocate it back. There are couple of setting which you can find in the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159206.aspx

try to set WorkingSetMinimum to higher number and you will see and imporovment when you restart reporting services next time but be careful not to overuse your memory for reporting service